# Eliminate repetition sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a table with users
I want to compare the same nicknames, whether there is repetition or not, I do not want to rule out repetition, I just want to know.
`let check_duble = await User.findAll({where: { username: username }})`

but my script, even if the same user has this nickname, it still says yes, how do I do?
`console.log(check_duble ? 'repeat' : 'don't repeat');`

Answer (score 0):

That's because `findAll` returns an array and that means it will always be truesh for ternary operator. SImply replace `findAll` with `count` and if you get more than 1 then you will get `don't repeat`:

```js
let check_duble = await User.count({where: { username: username }})
console.log((check_duble > 1) ? 'repeat' : 'don't repeat');
```